# passing multiple sub report source path

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I am having one main report which has a sub-report and sub-report itself has one more sub-report.. 3 level hierarchy.. one sub-report is working fine,but sub-report inside sub-report is throwing exception

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : C:\Users\Tejas.Kotekar\Desktop\DMA\WebContent\jasperReport\ComplaintReport_subreport1_subreport2.jasper..

How to put the second sub-report path in map..

This is my java code

```
    String subReportSource = Filepaths.getfilepath() + 
ReportConstant.JASPER_REPORT_NAME + MainetConstants.FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR;

            map.put(ReportConstant.SUB_REPORT_DIR_NAME, subReportSource);

            String jrxmlFileLocation = Filepaths.getfilepath() + 
ReportConstant.JASPER_REPORT_NAME  + Constants.FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR +
 "ComplaintReport.jrxml";
```